# how to send data from raspberry pi to a webpage?

Tags: python

I'm working on a personal project, my problem is I wan to send the output of my deep learning model (prediction model) running on the raspberry pi to a webpage so that I may process it in a database, plot the result, and perform other operations on it. but i have no idea how to do it, the code I use is below,  thanks to the owner of the source code

```
import cv2  
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
model = keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5')
data_for_model = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)


def load_labels(path):
  f = open(path, 'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  labels = []
  for line in lines:
    labels.append(line.split(' ')[1].strip('\n'))
  return labels


label_path = 'labels.txt'
labels = load_labels(label_path)
print(labels)



def image_resize(image, height, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
  dim = None
  (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
  r = height / float(h)
  dim = (int(w * r), height)
  resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
  return resized



def cropTo(img):
  size = 224
  height, width = img.shape[:2]

  sideCrop = (width - 224) // 2
  return img[:, sideCrop:(width - sideCrop)]


while True:
  ret, img = webcam.read()
  if ret:
   
    img = image_resize(img, height=224)
    img = cropTo(img)

 
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

   
    normalized_img = (img.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
    data_for_model[0] = normalized_img


    prediction = model.predict(data_for_model)
    for i in range(0, len(prediction[0])):
      print('{}: {}'.format(labels[i], prediction[0][i]))
    cv2.imshow('webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Sample Output:

```
bottle: 0.9784454107284546
cup: 0.04396909475326538
bottle: 0.9560309052467346
cup: 0.04825812205672264
bottle: 0.9517418742179871
cup: 0.01662440039217472
bottle: 0.983375608921051
```

Comment: If your model generates output periodically you can do is in a loop. Collect all your data within a timeframe and `post` it to your webpage. I propose using [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html)

Comment: thank willl try this also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` `bash` command via `python`.

I am new to `StackOverflow`, but once I faced the same situation during my personal project with CV, I googled for it and got this [site](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/02/21/send-data-from-rpi-to-server). Check it out, may help!

Comment: thank you, will try this method and give feedback if it`s working